# Need to combine two impure observables

Tags: javascript, angular2-observables

I need to make 2 AJAX requests to the same endpoint that would return filtered and unfiltered data. Then I need to combine results and use them both in processing.

```
    loadUnfilteredData() {
        // remember status
        const {status} = this.service.filters;
        delete this.service.filters.status;
        this.service.saleCounts$()
            .subscribe((appCounts) =>
                this.processUnfilteredData(appCounts)
            );
        // restore status
        if (status) {
            this.service.filters.status = status;
        }
    }

    loadFilteredData() {
        this.service.saleCounts$()
            .subscribe((appCounts) =>
                this.processFilteredData(appCounts)
            );
    }
```

The problem is that `this.service.saleCounts$()` is impure and instead of using arguments just uses `this.service.filters`.
That's why i have to store the `status`, then delete it from filter, then do the request, and then restore (because same filter is used by other requests).

So I can't just do `combineLatest` over two observables (because i need to restore).

Is there any workaround?

(p.s. I know the approach is disgusting, i know about state management and about pure functions. Just wanted to know is there any beautiful solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your constraints require that the two operations are run sequentially , one after the other, rather than in parallel as is generally the case when we're using `combineLatest`.

To run two Observables sequentially, we can use `switchMap` (as an operator inside a `pipe` call in modern rxjs):

```
doFirstOperation()
    .pipe(
        switchMap(result => return doSecondOperation())
    );
```

One potential issue with that is that you lose access to the result of `doFirstOperation` when you `switchMap` it to the result of `doSecondOperation`. To work around that, we can do something like:

```
doFirstOperation()
    .pipe(
        switchMap(firstResult => return doSecondOperation())
            .pipe(
                map(secondResult => [firstResult, secondResult])
            )
    );
```

i.e., use `map` to change the returned value of `switchMap` to be an array including both values.

Putting this together with your "disgusting" requirements for state management, you could use something like:

```
  loadData() {
    const { status } = this.service.filters;
    delete this.service.filters.status;
    return this.service
      .saleCounts$()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          if (status) {
            this.service.filters.status = status;
          }
        }),
        switchMap(filteredData => {
          return this.service
            .saleCounts$() // unfiltered query
            .pipe(map(unfilteredData => [filteredData, unfilteredData]));
        })
      )
      .subscribe(results => {
        const [filteredData, unfilteredData] = results;
        this.processFilteredData(filteredData);
        this.processUnfilteredData(unfilteredData);
      });
  }
```

I'm not too many people would categorize that is beautiful, but it does at least allow you to get results in a way that looks like you used `combineLatest`, yet works around the constraints imposed by your impure method.